# Finding the "least" singular solution for NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I need to solve a ODE for a function $f_\sigma(x)$, where $\sigma$ is a free parameter to tune. All the solutions are supposed to be singular for some value of $x$, except one for a given value $\sigma=\sigma^*$. $f_\sigma(x)$ behaves nicely for every $x$, and as I get close to $\sigma^*$, the value at which $f(x)$ diverges moves further away (i.e. to larger $x$).

I need to find $\sigma^*$. My idea would be to do a iterative procedure in which I compute $f_\sigma(x)$ for different values $\sigma$, and then focus on the range of values for which the singularity happens the latest (the largest $x$). However I do not know how to extract this information from NDSolve.

```
kd = (2^(d - 1) π^(d/2) Gamma[d/2]);
d = 3;
ext = 100;
s2[σ_] := 
  NDSolve[{f''[p] -  2 f[p] f'[p] + (1 + d/2) f[p] + (1 - d/2) p f'[p] == 0,  
           f'[0] == σ, 
           f[0] == 0
          }, f[p], {p, 0, ext}
  ]
```

Doing for example `s2[-.3]`, Mathematica tells me

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At p == 4.160343901296758`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

From this I would like to extract the value `p=4.1603.....`, but I do not know how to do this.

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the overall conclusions of this answer are unchanged, **details  have been edited substantially**.

I surmise from the question and comments that the OP is seeking a solution to the ODE that does not grow exponentially at large `p`.  Two solutions already identified are `f[p] = 0` and `f[p] = p`.  In addition to these trivial solutions, another exists near `σ = -0.228601`, and other answers have focused on obtaining more accurate values for this `σ`.  Unfortunately, even with highly accurate values for `σ`, `f[p]` has been computed only for modest values of `p`.  This answer takes a different approach, finding the desired `f[p]` directly and determining the corresponding `σ` only as a byproduct.

If `f[p]` is not to explode in magnitude for large `p`, `f''[p]` must be small compared to other terms in the ODE.  So, let us drop this term from the ODE to obtain an asymptotic equation, which can be solved for `f'[p]`.

```
Solve[- 2 f[p] f'[p] + (1 + d/2) f[p] + (1 - d/2) p f'[p] == 0, f'[p]][[1, 1]]
(* f'[p] -> (5 f[p])/(p + 4 f[p]) *)
```

As shall be seen, `f[p]` is approximately equal to `p` for large `p`, so, `f'[p]` approaches `1` asymptotically.  This is sufficient information to obtain the desired solution, computed out to `pmax = 10000`.

```
pmax = 10000; 
{a1, a2} = NDSolveValue[{f''[p] - 2 f[p]  f'[p] + (1 + d/2) f[p] + (1 - d/2) p f'[p] == 0, 
    f[0] == 0, - 2 f[pmax]  f'[pmax] + (1 + d/2) f[pmax] + (1 - d/2) pmax f'[pmax] == 0},
    {f, f'}, {p, 0, pmax}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxSteps -> 10^6, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[pmax] == pmax - 1754/100,
    - 2 f[pmax] f'[pmax] + (1 + d/2) f[pmax] + (1 - d/2) pmax f'[pmax] == 0}}];

Plot[{a1[p], a2[p]}, {p, 0, 10.4}, AxesLabel -> {p, "f, f'"}, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 7}}]
```

[image]

which agrees with the plot in my earlier answer for as far as the former is valid.  However, the current answer is valid to `p -> 10000`.  As an accuracy test (as suggested by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)),

```
a1[0]
(* -1.43919293846595796615*10^-11 *)
σ = a2[0]
(* -0.22859820245788122180105821189 *)
```

The accuracy of σ, although good, agrees with [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)'s value only to ten significant figures.  However, that is beside the point.  By integrating from large `p` to small `p` rather than the reverse, an excellent value for `σ` is not needed.

To plot the solution over the entire range, {p, 0, 10000}, it is convenient to do so in terms of a new dependent variable.

```
g[p] = f[p] - p
LogLogPlot[{-b1[p] + p, -b2[p] + 1, b2'[p]}, {p, .01, pmax}, 
    AxesLabel -> {p, "-g, -g', g''"}]
```

[image]

where the blue and orange curves are `-g[p]` and `-g'[p]`, and the green curve is `g''[p]`.  As expected, `f''[p] = g''[p]` is very small asymptotically, and `g[p] = f[p] - p` is much less than `p`.

As an aside, the asymptotic ODE can be solved to obtain the asymptotic solution.  First, substitute `g` for `f`,

```
Simplify[Unevaluated[D[f[p], p, p] - 2 f[p] D[f[p], p] + (1 + d/2) f[p] + 
    (1 - d/2) p D[f[p], p] ] /. f[p] -> p + g[p]]
(* 1/2 (g[p] - 5 p g'[p] - 4 g[p] g'[p] + 2 g''[p] *)
```

drop the second derivative term, and solve using `DSolve`.

```
dsol = DSolveValue[g[p] - 5 p g'[p] - 4 g[p] g'[p] == 0, g[p], p] /. C[1] -> Log[c]
(* Root[-c p - c #1 + #1^5 &, 1] *)
```

The constant `c` can be determined by fitting the asymptotic solution to the full solution above.

```
FindRoot[(dsol /. p -> pmax) == a1[pmax] - pmax, {c, -167}][[1]]
(* c -> -166.625 *)
```

The same calculation for `pmax = 1000` yields `c -> -166.457`, indicating that the asymptotic state has indeed been reached.

Comment: I'm not sure what to think about this method (other than it's clever).  The value obtained for `σ = a1'[0]` does not seem to be very good....Or do you have an argument why it is?

Comment: @MichaelE2  For this answer I took as a goal not to obtain a better value for `σ` but to obtain a solution for `f` that satisfies `a1[0] =0` reasonably well ( `-6.8455349099784265381*10^-12` for `WorkingPrecision->30`) and is valid to `p = 100`.  I shall update my second answer now with this higher precision result.  Thanks for the question.

Comment: Fair enough, but it seems clear the question asks how to estimate the critical value σ*.  One could push this method to `Infinity` (I think), but it's not clear one gets a more accurate estimate of the critical value σ* the further one goes.  Integrating this vector field (ode) backwards seems stable, but I don't know how to estimate the error. OTOH, it's not clear that shooting as far as one can from `p == 0`, as in the other answers, is superior either....If I get a chance, I'll think about it.  This method might actually *reduce* error.

Comment: The Q says, "I need to find σ*." That's what I was thinking of. Maybe someone added that.  In any case, getting it to 11 digits is probably much more than anyone needs in practice. Assuming they're correct. :)

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks, the answer looks great. I will probably need this for the future. A couple of questions. How did you see that asymptotically f[p]=p? and how did you other term in the initial shooting condition, f[pmax] == pmax - 1754/100?

Comment: @bnado  Based on the plot in my first answer, I guessed that `f'[p]` becomes constant asymptotically.  Plugging that into the asymptotic expression for `f'[p]` in the current answer shows that `f'[p]` must be either `+1` or `-1`.  Only the former makes sense.  I obtained the initial guess of `pmax - 1754/100` by first computing the solution for `pmax = 1000` with an initial guess of `989` and then using `dsol` to extrapolate the guess to `pmax = 10000`.  I obtained the `pmax = 1000` guess by trial and error.  By the way, please accept one of the answers, if useful.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

The point at which the integration halts can be determined by

```
pf[σ_?NumericQ] := NDSolveValue[{f''[p] - 2 f[p] f'[p] + (1 + d/2) f[p] + (1 - d/2) p f'[p]
  == 0, f'[0] == Rationalize[σ, 0], f[0] == 0}, f, {p, 0, ext}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
  ["Domain"][[1, 2]] 

pf[-.3]
(* 4.83068220440801267749372370940 *)
```

**Addendum**

Adding `WorkingPrecision -> 30` and `Rationalize[σ, 0]` to the definition of `pf` proves helpful.  Then,

```
pf[1]
(* 100.000000000000000000000000000 *)
pf[-0.228598202]
(* 10.0150679186698881369975149637 *)
```

So, there may be another solution very near `-0.228598202`, and

```
Quiet@FindRoot[pf[σ == 100, {σ, -0.228598202}, WorkingPrecision -> 30][[1, 2]]
(* -0.228598202437027556607595293218 *)
```

should find it (if it exists), but the computation is painfully slow.  Moreover, the improvement is modest in this case

```
pf[%]
(* 10.3369620229137045868752090085 *)
```

So, at this level of precision the solution just found is not very good.  For completeness, here is a plot of the corresponding function and its derivative

```
s = %%; plt = Quiet@s2[s]; Quiet@
Plot[{plt[p], plt'[p]}, {p, 0, pf[s]}, AxesLabel -> {p, "f, f'"}, PlotRange -> {-1, 7}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I modified your `NDSolve` a bit for convenience (`NDSolveValue` to get rid of the rule, and `f` instead of `f[p]` to get a pure function):

```
s2[σ_] := 
 NDSolveValue[{f''[p] - 2 f[p] f'[p] + (1 + d/2) f[p] + (1 - d/2) p f'[p] == 0, 
   f'[0] == σ, f[0] == 0}, f, {p, 0, ext}]
```

`s2[σ]["Domain"]` can be used to inspect the domain. Now examining a range of sigmas:

```
Table[{σ, s2[σ]["Domain"][[1, 2]] // Quiet}, {σ, -5, 5, .05}] // ListPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks like there are three candidate positions. Examining their neighborhood:

```
ListPlot[
  Table[{σ, s2[σ]["Domain"][[1, 2]] //Quiet}, {σ, -0.229, -0.2284, .0000001}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[
  Table[{σ,s2[σ]["Domain"][[1, 2]] // Quiet}, {σ, -0.001, 0.001, .00002}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[
  Table[{σ, s2[σ]["Domain"][[1, 2]] // Quiet}, {σ, 0.99999, 1.00001, .0000001}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks like the one at σ = 0 is the winner. X runs up to its full range at 100.

Comment: The problem with σ = 0 is that it yields `f` identically zero.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Where in the question did you read that that should not be happening?  ;-)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Indeed f idetically zero is not the interesting solution. The actual value should be something around -0.228601... which is between the other two candidates in your theory! Thank you very much for the answer

Comment: @bnado  It appears that `1` works well, as I shall show in a mod to my answer soon.

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes that indeed works. Basically 1 and 0 are the "boring" solutions that I'm not interested into, while -0.22... is a physically interesting one. So for these three points I should get no divergence

Comment: @bnado Indeed, there is another maxima at near -0.228598202, but I am trying to find a more accurate value.

Answer (score 1):

One can find the value the last value in the domain of an interpolating function `ifn` with any of the following:

```
ifn["Domain"][[-1, -1]]
ifn["Grid"][[-1, -1]]
ifn["Coordinates"][[-1, -1]]
```

To maximize, now that we have an expression for it, we can use [`FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html).  A slight alteration of the OP's `s2`, similar to [Sjoerd's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57/sjoerd-c-de-vries), to make it easier to get at the `InterpolatingFunction`.

```
ClearAll[s2];
With[{kd = (2^(d - 1) π^(d/2) Gamma[d/2]), d = 3},
 s2[σ_?NumericQ] := Quiet[
    NDSolveValue[
     {f''[p] - 2 f[p] f'[p] + (1 + d/2) f[p] + (1 - d/2) p f'[p] == 0, 
      f'[0] == σ, f[0] == 0},
     f, {p, 0, Infinity}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> Precision[σ]],
    NDSolveValue::ndsz]
 ]
```

Machine precision will be much faster:

```
obj[s_?NumericQ] := s2[s]["Domain"][[-1, -1]];
{resmp, solmp} = FindMaximum[obj[σ], {σ, -0.225}]
```

> FindMaximum::sdprec: Line search unable to find a sufficient increase in the function value with MachinePrecision digit precision. >>

```
(*  {10.903, {σ -> -0.228598}}  *)
```

We can use the machine precision result as a start for the higher precision search:

```
{res, sol} = FindMaximum[obj[σ], {σ, σ /. solmp}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

> FindMaximum::sdprec: Line search unable to find a sufficient increase in the function value with 20.` digit precision. >>

```
(*  {12.182688412696092583, {σ -> -0.22859820215629144528}}  *)
```

More precision, slightly longer interval, but much, much more time to compute:

```
{res, sol} = FindMaximum[obj[σ], {σ, σ /. solmp}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

FindMaximum::sdprec: Line search unable to find a sufficient increase in the function value with 30.` digit precision. >>

```
(*
  {13.5616831717857365714489087304, 
   {σ -> -0.228598202437027556607597968677}}
*)
```