# solve tricky nonlinear ODE on a grid

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I've been working on the same question for a while now and would appreciate any advice on what I'm doing wrong or any direction on how to actually solve the problem.  :)  On xzczd's advice, I retried with just using NDSolve.  Also on xzczd's advice, I simplified the problem so that it is copy-paste-runnable.

Here's explicit code of what I'm doing.

```
(* Parameters *)
α = 4/100; γ = 2; ψ = 2; A = 1/10; θ = 10; δ = 0; σ = 1/10;

(* Define a function *)
ϕ[i_] := i - θ/2 i^2 - δ;

(* Boundaries *)
b = Rationalize[0.11619,10^-10]; (* Rationalize common-valued boundary point s*)

(* Some functions for ODE and solution to i *)
l1 = (1 - z) (1 - z y'[z]/y[z]);
l2 = z (1 + (1 - z) y'[z]/y[z]);
m = z^2 (1 - z)^2 y''[z]/y[z];

(* Solve for i as a function of y and y' *)
isolve = FullSimplify[Solve[{
 (((A - i1) (1 - z) + (A - i2) z)/y[z])^(1/ψ) == α/(ϕ'[i1] (y[z] - z y'[z])),
 (((A - i1) (1 - z) + (A - i2) z)/y[z])^(1/ψ) == α/(ϕ'[i2] (y[z] + (1 - z) y'[z]))}, {i1, i2}]];

(* There are three potential solutions here.  Only the first is
correct, I believe *)
Dimensions[isolve]
i1star = i1 /. isolve[[1, 1]]; 
i2star = i2 /. isolve[[1, 2]];
cstar = (A - i1star) (1 - z) + (A - i2star) z;

(* Simplify ODE *)
ode = Simplify[ ( α/(1 - 1/ψ) ((cstar/y[z])^(1 - 1/ψ) - 1) + ϕ[i1star] l1 + ϕ[i2star] l2 - γ /
    2 (σ^2 l1^2 + σ^2 l2^2) + (σ^2 + σ^2)m/2) ] == 0;

(* Attempt at solution with NDSolve *)
sol = NDSolve[{ode, y[1/100] == b, y[99/100] == b}, y, {z, 1/100, 99/100}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[1/100] == b, 
  y'[1/100] == Rationalize[0.1536914, 10^-10]}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

As you can see, I'm starting to shoot from within the boundary, to sidestep the end-point singularities.  The solution, I know, looks effectively (negative) quadratic, with endpoints at the boundaries.  I was previously implementing a finite difference method because it seemed to deal with the end-points singularities better (I only solved on the interior of the grid).  It also seemed to solve quickly.

My question is: is there a better, more robust way to solve this than shooting?  Or is the math what it is and that's that?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you'd better add a specific working example rather than describe the problem in such an abstract way, or it's hard to give advice. With the information you've mentioned so far, I'll guess that the trouble might lie in `FindRoot` because solving a large nonlinear system with it can be troublesome and a good starting point is very important for `FindRoot`  to give a proper answer. BTW, just to make sure, you need to solve the ODE _yourself_ rather than using `NDSolve`, right?

Comment: Hi xzczd.  Thanks for your reply.  I was hoping someone like you was going to respond.  I've read a lot of your online help about solving ODEs with NDSolve.  I tried--A LOT-- with just NDSolve, but I found the shooting method to be unreliable in solving.  I believe the problem is that the ODE is singular at both boundary points.  By doing differencing myself, I was able to solve a simpler version of the problem and the differencing seemed to be much more robust.  I'm still learning.

Comment: There's a typo in the definition of `bi` and I can't figure out how to fix it. And… currently your big code sample is a little frustrating, it'll be better if you can simplify the code sample a little, for example, the code calculating `bi` and `b` and `ode` isn't relevant, you can just give the result in the sample. If you're not sure whether your deductions for them are correct or not so want us to have a check (it's deprecated, of course), at least add a description for the original problem, I mean, you can express the problem with some equations (in traditional mathematical form).

Comment: This sounds like a related Q&A: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/nonlinear-differential-equation-numerical-solution/97733#97733

Comment: @MichaelE2 Actually yesterday I tried to use the method you mentioned in the answer to solve OP's problem but failed 囧, seems that OP's case is more complicated. (Maybe I haven't fully understand your answer.)

Comment: @xzczd It certainly **looks** complicated, but in part that's because it's not copy-pasteable.  I don't have time to fix it up right now & explore.  I think Jane Doe would be more likely to get help if the syntax errors were cleaned up.

Comment: Hi xzczd, MichaelE2, thanks for your feedbkac

Comment: Hi xzczd, MichaelE2.  Thanks for your feedback and sorry for the previous comment.  I've been traveling and unable to address your comments until now.  I simplified the code so that it should be copy-paste-runnable in MMA v10.3.  The simplification basically involved just entering the value of the boundary rather than calculating it.  I don't think it is fruitful to simplify any other part of the code.  Feel free to disagree.  I'm still learning.

Comment: I agree that the link you posted, MichaelE2, is related to my problem.  Thanks.  I'll take a look and learn from it.

Comment: Well, you need to add a _at_ in front of our names i.e. write something like @MichaelE2 in your comment, or we won't receive the reminder. (BTW, you can remind only one non-author person commenting/editing the question/answer in a comment.) Then, does the code sample work in v10 or it's just a ineffectual trial? In v9 it fails, at least with the current initial guess.

Comment: @xzczd It's an ineffectual trial.  I'm stuck.  I looked at Michael's link and started working through the shooting solution but still haven't gotten anywhere.  My problem is a lot messier than the one in the link.  I'm sorry that I'm not being clear enough.  I'm even learning how to operate Stack Exchange

Comment: @xzczd Don't worry about this example.  I've given up.  It's too hard for me.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Update: I solved this in 3 hours with Matlab.  Wow.

Answer (score 2):

This computation is failing, because

```
(-((y[z] (y[z] + (1 - 2 z) y'[z])^2 (y[z] - z y'[z]))/(y[z] - (-1 + z) y'[z])^2))^(1/3)
```

is complex for typical initial conditions given in the question.  Evidently, the wrong branch of cube root has been chosen.  Instead, use `Surd` to assure that the real root is chosen (if it exists).  To do so, modify the original ODE in the question as shown.

```
pode = ode /. Power[x__, 1/3] -> Surd[x, 3] /. Power[x__, 2/3] -> Surd[x, 3]^2 
    /. Power[x__, -1/3] -> 1/Surd[x, 3]
(* 1/100 (-8 + 4/5 2^(2/3) Sqrt[Surd[(y[z] (y[z] + (1 - 2 z) y'[z])^2 (y[z] - 
   z y'[z]))/(y[z] - (-1 + z) y'[z])^2, 3]/(y[z] (y[z] - z y'[z]))] - ...) *)
```

(The entire expression is quite long.)  Then, after a bit of experimentation, the ODE with its boundary conditions can be solved by

```
sol = NDSolve[{pode, y[1/100] == b, y[99/100] == b}, {y, y'}, {z, 1/100, 99/100}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y'[1/100] == .94777}}];
Plot[(y[z] /. sol), {z, 0.01, .99}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

For completeness, the value `y'[1/100]` obtained by `NDSolve` is

```
(y'[z] /. sol) /. z -> .01
(* {0.947771} *)
```

It appears that a very good initial guess is needed, because the solution is near a separatrix of the ODE.  The solution can be obtained in a more automated manner using approaches such as those given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147585/1063).