# While loop with infinitesimal steps is too time consuming

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I have two ODEs with initial conditions. I want to solve the system such that $10^{-4}<z[x]<z_{0}$. The difficulty of problem is here that the initial conditions in not fixed but the boundary values are fixed. I've tried very hard to find the solution and plot them. Given the initial conditions $z[0]=z_{0}$ and $v[0]=v_{0}$ the code below find the solution BUT i don't know how to implement the other Boundary conditions $z[L/2]=10^{-4}$ and $v[L/2]=t$. where $z_{0}>0$ and $v_{0},t\in R$.

```
eqs[z0_] := {D[
  z[x]^(2 (1 - ξ)) F[v[x], z[x]] v'[x] + 
   z[x]^(1 - ξ)  z'[x], x] - 
 z[x]^(2 (1 - ξ)) D[F[v[x], z[x]], v[x]] v'[x]^2/2 == 0, 
D[z[x]^(1 - ξ) v'[x], x] - 
 dθ/z[x] (z0/z[x])^(2 dθ) - 
 z[x]^(2 (1 - ξ)) D[F[v[x], z[x]], z[x]] v'[x]^2/
  2 - (1 - ξ) z[
   x]^-ξ (z'[x] + z[x]^(1 - ξ) F[v[x], z[x]] v'[x]) v'[
   x] == 0};
F[v_, z_] := 1 - M[v] z^(dθ + ξ);
M[v_] := 1/2 (1 + Tanh[v/a]);
dθ = 
d - θ; θ = 2/3; ξ = 1.5; d = 2; a = 0.5; L = 8;

Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];

exsurf[v0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ] :=
{v[L/2], z[L/2]} /. 
NDSolve[Join[
  eqs[z0], {v[0] == v0, z[0] == z0, v'[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0}], {v, 
  z}, {x, 0, L/2}, MaxSteps -> Infinity,
 Method -> {"EventLocator", 
   "Event" -> z[x] < 5 10^-4 || z[x] > z0, 
   "EventAction" -> "StopIntegration"}][[1]];
```

once the problem is solved the solutions should be plotted as below
[image: the plot for $z[x]$]

In summary,

How can I find the values of $z_{0}$ and $v_{0}$ such that the other boundary conditions satisfied?

EDIT 1:

I can write a simple `While` loop to find `z0` for a given `L` and `v0` in a automated manner. Using the methods of @george2079 and @bbgodgrey i realized that sum of the correct values of `z0` and `v0` should be at least 10-digit precision e.g. if one choose `v0=0.09` the output value of `z0` is at least `1.11528215`. In fact such a very accurate results with below `While` loop is too time consuming since we must put the `surprof[L,t0]` into a table and vary `t0` e.g. between `[-5,5]` for a given `L`.

I don't have any idea how to effectively write a loop to do this.

```
surfprof[L_, v0_] := Block[{z0new, end, cut, area, v, z, x, sol},
z0new = .01;
sol = NDSolve[
 Join[eqs[z0new], {v[0] == v0, z[0] == z0new, v'[0] == 0, 
   z'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[10^-4 > z[x] || z[x] > z0new, 
    "StopIntegration"]}], {v, z}, {x, 0, L/2}, 
 MaxSteps -> Infinity][[1]];
end = InterpolatingFunctionDomain[First[z /. sol]][[1, -1, 2]];
While[
end != L/2,
sol = NDSolve[
  Join[eqs[z0new], {v[0] == v0, z[0] == z0new, v'[0] == 0, 
    z'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[10^-4 > z[x] || z[x] > z0new, 
     "StopIntegration"]}], {v, z}, {x, 0, L/2}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity][[1]];
end = InterpolatingFunctionDomain[First[z /. sol]][[1, -1, 2]];
z0new = z0new + 10^-6;
];
{Plot[{v[x], z[x]} /. sol, {x, 0, end}], {L, v0, z0new , cut, area, 
v[L/2], z[L/2]} /. sol}
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

changing to use `WhenEvent` and I fixed the parameters to be rationals, and change `l` to `el` for readability:

```
  \[Theta] = 2/3; \[Xi] = 3/2; d = 2; a = 1/2; el = 8;
```

now make a function that returns zero in case the integration ended early:

```
exsurf[v0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ] := Module[{},
   sol = NDSolve[Join[eqs[z0], {
        v[0] == v0,
        z[0] == z0,
        v'[0] == 0,
        z'[0] == 0,
        WhenEvent[10^-4 > z[x] > z0, "StopIntegration"]}], {v, z}, {x,
        0, el/2}, MaxSteps -> Infinity][[1]];
   tmax = (v["Domain"] /. sol)[[1, -1]];
   If[tmax < el/2 , {0, 0} , {v[el/2], z[el/2]} /. sol ]];
```

now plot `z[el/2]` as a function of `v0` for a particular `z0` (suggested by your plot )

```
 Plot[ Evaluate[exsurf[v0, 4.8]][[2]] , {v0, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

there looks to be a solution around `-6` :

```
Plot[ Evaluate[exsurf[v0, 4.8]][[2]] , {v0, -6.2732, -6.273}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, .1}]
```

[image]

```
exsurf[-6.27313, 4.8]
Plot[Evaluate[{v[x], z[x]} /. sol ], {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

a few more solutions found by hand:

```
Show[{
  exsurf[-6.27313, 4.8] ; Plot[Evaluate[{v[x], z[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, 4}],
  exsurf[-2.56561, 3]   ; Plot[Evaluate[{v[x], z[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, 4}],
  exsurf[-.0961850, 1.2]; Plot[Evaluate[{v[x], z[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, 4}],
  exsurf[2.197003, 1]   ; Plot[Evaluate[{v[x], z[x]} /. sol] ,{x, 0, 4}]}]
```

[image]

I think this thing is so nonlinear you need to manually approach it, and if you really want to chase down the exact "10^-4" point you will need to increase `WorkingPrecision`

Comment: Exact answer.Very thanks. but How do i find the exact location of `v0` i.e. around -6 above? OR is there a systematic way to find the location of `v0` having the value of `z0` instead of trial and error method? (In fact, i have a code that given `z0` automatically find suitable `v0` and  plotted its corresponding graph.)

Comment: how do you find the above values of `v0` with such accuracy? Please show your details. Thanks

Comment: I just manually varied the plot range to zero in on the solution.  I suspect because the character of the solution changes so abruptly that automating the procedure would not work very well.

Comment: I wrote a `while` loop to find the suitable `z0` for a given `v0`. This loop works well but when `v0` get closer to zero the BCs well not satisfy carefully. In the other words, when i use `v0=-0.09` instead of your exact result `v0=-.0961850` the BCs meet badly . Where is my wrong? i think i should increase, as you stated, `WorkingPrecision` but i don't know how?

Comment: I used `Rationalize` in Code and increased the `WorkingPrecision` of `NDSolve` but the obtained result was the same as previous! Please give me some advice. I don't know how to overcome this issue.

Comment: I added the `While` loop. Why this loop is too time consuming?

Answer (score 3):

I took the excellent answer and subsequent comment by [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) as a challenge to obtain accurate answers to the original question in a (nearly) automated manner.  It is convenient to begin by determining the value of `z0` for with `z''[0] == 0`, because the ODE and boundary conditions cannot be satisfied for `z''[0] > 0`.

```
z''[0] /. Flatten@Solve[eqs[z0] /. x -> 0 /. {v[0] -> v0, z[0] -> z0, v'[0] -> 0, 
    z'[0] -> 0}, {v''[0], z''[0]}]
f[v0_] = (xxx /. Flatten@Solve[0 == z0 % /. z0^(17/6) -> xxx, xxx])^(6/17)
LogPlot[{f[v0], g[v0]}, {v0, -4, 4}, AxesLabel -> {v0, f}]
(* 2^(6/17) (1/(1 + Tanh[2 v0]))^(6/17) *)
```

[image]

Next, define the parametric solution to the ODE

```
s = ParametricNDSolve[{eqs[z0], v[0] == v0, z[0] == z0, v'[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0}, {v, z}, 
    {x, 0, l/2}, {v0, z0, wp}, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```

Then, a more accurate determination of the range of `z0` for which `s` can be computed to at least as far as `l/2` can be obtained from (here for `v0 == 0`)

```
plt = Plot[Quiet@(z[#, z0, 15]["Domain"] /. s)[[1, 2]], {z0, 1, f[#]},
    PlotRange -> All] &[0]
Flatten[{First@First[#], First@Last[#]} & /@ DeleteCases[SplitBy[
    Cases[plt, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity] // Last, Last], a_ /; Length[a] == 1]]
```

[image]

```
(* {1.1521, 1.16959} *)
```

Thus, `z0` must lie in the range just computed to solve the ODE and boundary conditions for `v0 == 0`.  Note that, for some value of `v0` two ranges of `z0` are possible.  For instance, with `v0 == -2` the same calculation yields

[image]

```
(* {2.64973, 2.8303, 5.36544, 16.8382} *)
```

This same computation can be performed for numerous values of `v0` in the ranges `{-4, 4}` in about 20 minutes on my four-processor PC.

```
{Range[-4, -2.4, .1], Range[-2.39, -2.31, .01], Range[-2.3, -1.6, .1],
    Range[-1.59, -1.51, .01], Range[-1.5, 4, .1]} // Flatten
edges = ParallelTable[
    pltt = Plot[Quiet@(z[#, z0, 15]["Domain"] /. s)[[1, 2]], 
        {z0, .99, f[#]}, PlotRange -> All] &[v0];
    edg = {v0, Flatten[{First@First[#], First@Last[#]} & /@ DeleteCases[
        SplitBy[Cases[pltt, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity] // Last, Last], 
        a_ /; Length[a] == 1]]}, 
{v0, %}]

(* {{-4., {3.84885, 283.457}}, {-3.9, {3.77187, 246.136}}, ...}*)
```

Plot this large table by means of

```
c1 = {First@#, (Last@#)[[1]]} & /@ edges;
c2 = {First@#, (Last@#)[[2]]} & /@ Cases[edges, a_ /; (Length@Last@a == 4)];
c3 = {First@#, (Last@#)[[3]]} & /@ Cases[edges, a_ /; (Length@Last@a == 4)];
c4 = {First@#, (Last@#)[[-1]]} & /@ edges;
spt = Position[edges, a_ /; (Length@a == 4)][[-1, 1]];
ListLogPlot[{c1, Join[c2, c4[[spt + 1 ;;]]], c3, c4[[;; spt]]}, 
    PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Behavior evidently is qualitatively different for `v0` less than or greater than about `-1`.  As it turns out, `l == 4` solutions for `v0 > -1` are in the asymptotic regime of this nonlinear ODE.  To obtain actual solutions, define

```
hh[v0_, bl0_, bu0_] := Module[{bl = N[bl0, 30], bu = N[bu0, 30], zt, bt},
    Do[bt = (bl + bu)/2; zt = Quiet@(z[v0, bt, 30] /. s); 
    If[zt["Domain"][[1, 2]] < l/2 || zt[4] < 10^-4, bl = bt, bu = bt], {i, 53}]; bu]
```

This function takes two guesses for `z0` bracketing the expected solution (i.e., one lying below the bottom curve in the plot just above, and one just below the next curve up), successively reduces the size of the bracketed region, and finally returns a quite accurate value of `z0` in less than a minute.  (It is based on [code used to solve question 97492](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97499/1063), which addresses a nonlinear ODE separatrix problem.)  For instance, with `v0 == -4`.

```
hh[-4, 1, 4]
Plot[Evaluate[Through[Through[{v, z}[-4, %, 30]][x]] /. s], {x, 0, 4}, 
    PlotRange -> All]
z[-4, %%, 30][4] /. s
(* 3.79653466338964906690023326519 *)
```

[image]

```
(* 0.00010003309239505600297 *)
```

Thus, the boundary condition `z[l/2] == 10^-4` is satisfied with a precision of better than `10^-3`.  Higher precision is not difficult to obtain.  Corresponding results for `v0 == 4` are

```
hh[4, .99, f[4]]
Plot[Evaluate[Through[Through[{v, z}[4, %, 30]][x]] /. s], {x, 0, 4}, 
    PlotRange -> All]
z[4, %%, 30][4] /. s
(* 0.999967679312725509392309112271 *)
```

[image]

```
(* 0.000100002269572818141432 *)
```

Although this process may seem rather lengthy, all that actually is needed to obtain an accurate numerical solution is the parametric solution `s` (the second block of code above), the definition of `hh`, and two reasonable initial guesses, which can be obtained as illustrated for `v0 == 0` in the third block of code.  Values of `z0` for `v0 == Range[-4, 4]` are

```
(* 3.79653466338964906690023326519, 3.25378157569201964527394466131, 
   2.64580775324334157983627578923, 1.90856596604480570876855195170,
   1.15207984399450601605171562722, 1.003820075484002909681470684009,
   1.000038775429121127770272366082, 0.999968958249007355677937267149
   0.999967679312725509392309112271 *)
```

It turns out that solutions for `z0` for `v0` near `-2` lie only between the bottom curve and the curve immediately above it in the fourth plot above.

Incidentally, I experimented with `FindRoot` and `FindMaximum`, which often work well with nonlinear ODE boundary-value problems, but did not obtain good results in this case.

**Sample solution for `l == 30`**

For large values of `l` the entire range of `v0` considered above, `{-4, 4}` falls in the asymptotic regime, and obtaining solutions is somewhat more difficult.  Consider `l == 30` and `v0 == -2`.  Begin as before,

```
plt = Plot[Quiet@(z[#, z0, 15]["Domain"] /. ss)[[1, 2]], {z0, 1, f[#]}, 
    PlotRange -> All] &[-2]
```

[image]

(Compare with third plot above.) Because the curve does not actually reach `x == l/2` but instead only about `x == 5`, we instead pick out the maximum point on the curve and points that bracket it.  (Proceeding as we did for `l = 8` would require `WorkingPrecision -> 30` and a very large value of `PlotPoints`, which could be prohibitively slow.)

```
Cases[plt, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity] // Last;
Position[%, Max[Last /@ %]][[1, 1]]
{First[%%[[% - 1]]], First[%%[[% + 1]]]}
(* 63 *)
(* {2.64485, 2.65461 *)
```

Now, define

```
dom[v0_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ] := Quiet@(v[v0, z0, 30]["Domain"] /. s)[[1, 2]]
gg[v0_, bl0_, bu0_] := Module[{bl = N[bl0, 30], bu = N[bu0, 30], bt, db},
    Do[bt = (bl + bu)/2; db = (bu - bl)/100; If[dom[v0, bt] - dom[v0, bt - db] > 0, 
    bl = bt, bu = bt], {i, 68}]; bt]
```

Basically, it works like `hh` but constructs a numerical first derivative to determine on which side of the peak in the curve that `bt` lies and uses that information to reduce the size of the bracketed region on that side.  Then,

```
rough = gg[-2, 2.645`30, 2.648`30]
z[-2, %, 30][15] /. s
(* 2.64593297120377738824924829263 *)
(* 0.588648194538264076985120037 *)
```

gives a rough solution for `z0`.  Refine it with

```
hh[-2, rough - 10^-15, rough]
```

where the `Do` limit in `hh` has been increased to `70`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Through[Through[{v, z}[-2, %, 30]][x]] /. s], {x, 0, 15}, 
    PlotRange -> All]
z[-2, %%, 30][15] /. s
rough - %%%
(* 2.64593297120377738824924570875 *)
```

[image]

```
(* 0.0001000074744809224181 *)
(* -2.58388*10^-24 *)
```

That the accurate solution differs from the `rough` solution by only about one part in `10^24` is indicative of the sensitivity of such separatrix-related computations.

Comment: Very Thanks @bbgodfrey for your fantastic and CREATIVE answer. But i have a question: is there anyway to use the loop structure (`While,Do,For`) to solve this system smoothly? I have issued similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147580/evaluating-while-loops-does-not-yield-anything?noredirect=1#comment396465_147580)

Comment: @Ali184 In general, the answer is "yes".  Please be a bit more specific in what you would like, and I can try to provide an example.

Comment: In fact, i want to reproduce some of results of [Arxive:1401.6088](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.6088.pdf), specially figs 2 and 3. In summary, we have two nonlinear ODEs with initial and boundary conditions which i explained them [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147070/event-locator-method-does-not-solve-correctly-a-system-of-nonlinear-odes?noredirect=1#comment395536_147070), in detail. but nobody helped me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not the answers above adequately address Figure 2 in the article?  To obtain help on Figure 3, I suggest that you ask a new question containing the relevant equations.  By the way, if you really want to use the shooting method instead of what I provided above, I suggest that you use `Method -> {"Shooting", ...}` instead of `Method -> {"EventLocator", ...}`.  However, I know from painful experience that the shooting method struggles with separatrix problems such as yours, although the small value of `l` may help some.

Comment: Surely above answers is adequate for getting discrete values of `v0` and `z0` BUT above problem is a part of a bigger one in which we should vary e.g. the values of `v0` continuously. In answers above the values of `v0` `z0` are find for a specific choice. because of this we should have a loop or a faster and more direct way to smoothly find the value of e.g. `z0` for a given `v0`.

Comment: @Ali184 For `z0` as a function of `v0` chosen randomly, I know no faster way than what I proposed.  For `z0` for a sequence of closely spaced `v0`, the initial guess for `z0` for the next value of `v0` can be extrapolated from values of `z0` determined from earlier values of `v0`.  Also, are you seeking a table of `z0` from which to obtain highly accurate plots of `v` and `z`, or a plot of `z0` as a function of `v0` over some range of `v0`?  If the latter, than about 100 `z0` fed into `ListPlot` should be sufficient and can be obtained in an hour or less using `Table` or `Do`.