# How to numerically solve this non-linear ODE with initial guess function

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have the following non-linear differential equation:

```
{r t''[r] + t'[r] - 1/r Sin[t[r]] Cos[t[r]] + (4 k)/\[Pi] Sin[t[r]]^2 
 - h r Sin[t[r]] - r Sin[t[r]] Cos[t[r]] == 0, 
 t[0] == \[Pi], t[Infinity] == 0}
```

with parameters `k` and `h`. Let's say for now `k=2/3` and `h=0`. I know that the solution can be well approximated by

```
t0[r_, r0_] := 2 Pi - 2 ArcTan[Exp[(r - r0)]] - 2 ArcTan[Exp[(r + r0)]]
```

with some positive `r0` on the order of 1. The function looks like this:

[image]

Also, one can probably replace the `Infinity` in the boundary conditions by some value `>10`.

**How can I use this knowledge to (numerically) solve the DE?**

So far, I tried replacing `Infinity` by `20` and using `NDSolve` with various simple (simple as in not requiring additional parameters) `Methods`. Sometimes I get a result, but they always look wrong, like this one:

[image]

I believe that the key here is to somehow use my knowledge of the approximate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems like this usually are challenging, because they involve integrating along the separatrix of a nonlinear ODE, and doing so is numerically unstable.  Therefore, no matter how well the initial conditions are chosen, the integration eventually will depart from the desired result.  Nonetheless, integration over a reasonable distance certainly is possible.  For instance, with the parameters given in the question,

```
r0 = 10^-2; rmax = 10;
s = NDSolveValue[{r t''[r] + t'[r] - 1/r Sin[t[r]] Cos[t[r]] + (4 k)/π Sin[t[r]]^2 - 
    h r Sin[t[r]] - r Sin[t[r]] Cos[t[r]] == 0, t[r0] == π, 
    t[rmax] == 0} /. h -> 0 /. k -> 2/3, t, {r, r0, rmax}]
Plot[s[r], {r, r0, rmax}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold, Black]]
```

[image]

However, integrating to `r = 15` or so will show instability.  Furthermore, other parameters may show other instability behavior, so some experimentation may be required.  More powerful, but also more burdensome, [approaches](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147585/1063) are available, if needed.

**Addendum - Improved Boundary Condition**

It often is helpful to solve the linearized ODE at large `r`.

```
(Series[(r t''[r] + t'[r] - 1/r Sin[t[r]] Cos[t[r]] + (4 k)/\[Pi] Sin[t[r]]^2 - 
    h r Sin[t[r]] - r Sin[t[r]] Cos[t[r]])/r, {t[r], 0, 1}] // Normal) == 0
Flatten@DSolve[%, t[r], r, Assumptions -> r > 0];
cf[e_]:= 100 Count[e, _BesselJ, Infinity] + 100 Count[e, _BesselY, Infinity] + LeafCount[e]
FullSimplify[% /. C[2] -> I Pi C[2]/2 /. C[1] -> C[1] - Pi C[2]/2 /. C[1] -> I C[1], 
    r > 0, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
(* (-1 - h - 1/r^2) t[r] + t'[r]/r + t''[r] == 0 *)
(* {t[r] -> BesselI[1, Sqrt[1 + h] r] C[1] + BesselK[1, Sqrt[1 + h] r] C[2]} *)
```

(The last two lines are needed to obtain an explicitly real solution.)  That the asymptotic solution contains `BesselI` is another indication that infinitesimal errors in numerical integration can cause the solution to diverge from the separatrix.  The asymptotic solution also can be used to obtain a more accurate boundary condition at large `r`.

```
asym = t[r] /. % /. C[1] -> 0;
bc = t'[r]/t[r] == D[asym, r]/asym /. r -> rmax
(* t'[rmax]/t[rmax] == (Sqrt[1 + h] (-BesselK[0, Sqrt[1 + h] rmax] - 
   BesselK[2, Sqrt[1 + h] rmax]))/(2 BesselK[1, Sqrt[1 + h] rmax]) *)
```

Using `bc` instead of `t[rmax] == 0` often permits good accuracy with smaller values of `rmax`.

Comment: Perfect, just playing with the start and end values of the interval did the trick for all the parameters that I was interested in. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer.  I added some material you may find useful.  Best wishes.