# Methods of Numerically Finding Function Minimizing Functional

Tags: differential-equations, physics, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity, variational-calculus

Say we have some functional like the following: $H = (\partial_yf(y))^2 -w(y) f(y)^2 +f(y)^4/2$. This is the functional for the Gross Pitaevskii equation. Lets say $w(y)$, the trapping potential in this case, is some simple inverted Gaussian just so we have an explicit equation to work with: $w(y) = e^{-y^2}$.

My question is, **what efficient methods are available in Mathematica for finding the function $f(y)$ that minimizes this functional**? I will outline two methods that I have found that are problematic, but I would love to know some alternatives!

### Variational Methods

We can use the variational methods. So I define my function and use NDSolve to solve the Euler-Lagrange equation. One issue I have here is that I don't know apriori what constraints I should use: since this gives me a 2nd order differential equation, I need 2 constraints. I set the derivative at y=0 to be 0, as I expect f(y) to be symmetric about y=0. Since I want the functional to be minimized, I use the fact that $f'(0)=0$ to also come up with the constraint that $f(0) = 1$. (To get this, I simple plugged the first constraint into the functional and solved for $f(0)$ that minimized the functional).

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
w[y_]:=E^(-(y)^2)
sol = NDSolve[{EulerEquations[f'[y]^2 - w[y]*f[y]^2 + f[y]^4/2, f[y], y] , f'[0] == 0,f[0]==1}, f, {y, -5, 5}]
```

However, the result I am getting is certainly not a minimum of the functional. If one plots the above solution, you see that $f(y)$ blows up as |y| increases, which clearly can not be minimizing the functional because the functional has a term that goes at $f(y)^4$ which should keep $f(y)$ from blowing up. Am I doing something incorrectly here? I believe the issue is that it's trying to find an extrema rather than a Minima, which is what I am specifically looking for. However I don't know how to force it to minimize. If there were some way to simple use NMinimize to get a function, that would be ideal.

### Discretize and Minimize

The other method I came up with may be the worst(most inefficient) way one could do this. The idea is the discretize y into pieces of size $\epsilon$, and treat each f[y] as an independent variable. One must also discretize the derivative as $f'[y] = (f[y]+f[y+\epsilon])/\epsilon$. Then you can directly minimize the functional as a function of N variables. The issue is that, if I want to know $f(y)$ with any precision, I need to make $\epsilon$ small, which means I have a very large number of variables. Thus, the minimization takes a very long time. Here is example code applying this to the above functional:

```
numbSite = 100;
var = Table[Subscript[\[Psi], i], {i, 0, numbSite - 1}];
\[Epsilon] = .1;
sites = Table[-\[Epsilon]*numbSite/2 + \[Epsilon]*i, {i, 1,numbSite}];

Ham2[var_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] :=
  Sum[((var[[i + 1]] - var[[i]])/\[Epsilon])^2, {i, 1, numbSite - 1}] - 
   Sum[(E^(-(-\[Epsilon]*numbSite/2 + \[Epsilon]*i)^2))*var[[i]]^2 , {i, 1, numbSite}] + 
(1/2)*Sum[var[[i]]^4, {i, 1, numbSite}];


min = FindMinimum[{Ham2[var]}, 
   Table[Subscript[\[Psi], i], {i, 0, numbSite - 1}], 
   MaxIterations -> 100];

p1 = ListPlot[
   Table[{sites[[i]], var[[i]]^2 /. min[[2]]}, {i, 1, numbSite}]];
```

This gives closer to the result I am expecting. It's still very slow when I make the number of sites large, but at least it is something.

I would love to hear any suggestions you have on solving this problem! Functionals of this form are very common in physics (due to the usefulness of the Landau-Ginzburg theory) and it would be great to have more efficient ways of minimizing them.

Answer (score 9):

I'd typically go for "discretize and optimize".

Here is a quick and dirty implementation of this strategy that avoids all symbolic computation and that utilizes Sobolev gradient descent with respect to the $H^1$ inner product to speed up the computations. See also [Can Mathematica solve Plateau's problem (...)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158356/38178) for a more sophisticated application of $H^1$ gradient descent.

(I have to sort of armwrestle `FindMininum` to convince it to use the correct gradient. But I cannot change `FindMininum`'s stopping criterion, so I stop it manually.)

In this example, I impose Dirichet boundary conditions.

```
n = 2001;
a = -5.;
b = 5.;
h = (b - a)/(n - 1);
w[y_] := E^(-(y)^2)
y = Subdivide[a, b, n - 1];
\[Omega] = w /@ y;

stiffness = SparseArray[
   {Band[{1, 1}] -> 2./h, Band[{2, 1}] -> -1./h, 
    Band[{1, 2}] -> -1./h},
   {n, n}
   ];
stiffness[[1, 1]] = 1./h;
stiffness[[-1, -1]] = 1./h;

mass = SparseArray[
   {Band[{1, 1}] -> 2./3 h, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1./6 h, 
    Band[{1, 2}] -> 1./6 h},
   {n, n}
   ];
mass[[1, 1]] = 1./3 h;
mass[[-1, -1]] = 1./3 h;

ClearAll[F];
\[Omega] = Total[mass] w /@ y;


F[f_?VectorQ] := With[{f2 = f f},
   f . stiffness . f - \[Omega] . f2 + 0.5 f2 . mass . f2
   ];
F'[f_?VectorQ] := With[{f2 = f f},
   2. f . stiffness - 2. \[Omega] f + (2. f2 . mass) f
   ];

stiffnessWithDirichletBnd = stiffness;
stiffnessWithDirichletBnd[[1]] = SparseArray[{1} -> 1., {n}];
stiffnessWithDirichletBnd[[-1]] = SparseArray[{n} -> 1., {n}];
solver = LinearSolve[stiffnessWithDirichletBnd, Method -> "Banded"];

H1GradientWithDirichlet[f_?VectorQ] := Module[{b},
   b = F'[f];
   b[[{1, -1}]] = {0., 0.};
   solver[b]
   ];

f0 = ConstantArray[1., n];

f0[[1]] = 1.;
f0[[-1]] = 2.;

Block[{f},
  {min, fmin} = Quiet@FindMinimum[F[f], {f, f0},
     Gradient :> H1GradientWithDirichlet[f],
     Method -> "Gradient",
     MaxIterations -> 30
     ];
  fmin = f /. fmin
  ];

"H1 Residual" -> Sqrt[# . stiffness . # + # . mass . #] &[
 H1GradientWithDirichlet[fmin]]

ListLinePlot[fmin, DataRange -> {a, b}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, could you mention which functional you are minimizing here? From reading your code, I don't know what role stiffness and mass are meant to play, so it's not obvious to me how to edit the code to work with the functional I started with.

Comment: I tried to minimize the very functional that you posted. `stiffness` is the socalled stiffness matrix, Gram matrix of the $H^1$ scalar product with respect to the basis of piecewise-linear "hat functions". This way `f.stiffness.f` is a discretization of $\int_a^b (\partial_y f(y))^2 \, \mathrm{d} y$. `mass` is the so-called mass matrix, the Gram matrix of the $L^2$ scalar product so that `f.mass.f` discretizes $\int_a^b (f(y))^2 \, \mathrm{d} y$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness_matrix.

Comment: Ahh I see, that makes sense! Could you also explain how \[Omega] relates to discretizing $e^(-y^2))$? Sorry for the confusion, I am actually totally unfamiliar with this technique! Running your code as is is unfortunately giving me some errors, the first being "The method "Banded" accepts only matrices with elements that are machine-real or machine-complex numbers".

Comment: Please try again; there were some definitions missing. `\[Omega] . f2` or `\[Omega] . (f f)` computes the integral $\int_a^b w(y) \, (f(y))^2 \, \mathrm{d} y$.

Comment: This is very cool, thank you for taking the time to write it out! Hopefully the last question, could you explain how I might change the code if I wanted to minimize the functional without the $\partial_y f(y)$ term, for example? I was thinking I would just multiply the stiffness terms in the definition of F and F' by 0, but this doesn't seem to give the correct result.

Comment: If you leave that term out, then there is nothing that keeps the solution smooth. I doubt that this modified problem would make any sense.

Comment: Actually, ignoring the derivative term in this functional is often referred to as the Thomas-Fermi approximation. One should expect that $f(y)^2 = w(y)$ minimizes the functional in this case, so it would be useful to be able to recover this simple result! Thank you!

Comment: I can reproduce the right side of your plot with `s[.7695]`, as defined in my answer.  However, the solution blows up at about `y = 5.7116`.  (I believe that the solution should be symmetric.)  In general, the solution is very sensitive to the value of f[0], because it is near a separatrix.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The discrepancy probably stems from the fact that instead of an initial value problem I solve a boundary value problem whose boundary data is completely unrelated to OP's initial value problem. I did so because it appeared to me that this would fit better to what OP was actually meaning to ask: namely solving an optimization problem, and boundary conditions somewhat more sense in this context.

Comment: I have to admit though, that a bounded domain with Dirichlet boundary conditions probably doesn't make sense here. OP probably wants to solve the optimization on the whole real line with some Sommerfeld-type conditions applied to the infinitely far boundaries.

Comment: I was wondering how one actually derives the stiffness and mass matrix. Here's how I would derive the functional to minimize. For the $\partial_y f^2$ term, I would use finite difference to get the derivative vector--let's call it $df$--where $df_i = (f_{i+1}-f_i)/h$. Then $\partial_y f^2 = df.df$. Then the other terms just come from something like f.f.f.f (this being taking the fourth power of y element wise). I am having a hard time understanding and finding a source on how to derive these stiffness and matrices.

Answer (score 3):

The variational method produces a different solution, if the second boundary condition given in the question, `f[0] ==1`, is replaced by `f[y]` vanishing in the limit that `y` goes to infinity.

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
w[y_] = E^(-(y)^2);
eq = MultiplySides[EulerEquations[f'[y]^2 - w[y]*f[y]^2 + f[y]^4/2,
    f[y], y], -1/2] // Expand
(* E^-y^2 f[y] - f[y]^3 + f''[y] == 0 *)
```

The desired solution is obtained by solving `eq` as a separatrix problem.

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, f'[0] == 0, f[0] == f0}, 
    f[y], {y, 0, 10000}, {f0}, WorkingPrecision -> 45];
Plot[Evaluate[s[.731896481277023]], {y, 0, 10000}, AxesLabel -> {y, f}]
```

[image]

which I obtained by hand from successive guesses for the argument of `s`.  This process can, of course, be automated, as in [147207](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147585/1063).  Comparing the result with the asymptotic solution show good agreement for large `y`,

```
sa = Simplify[DSolveValue[f'[y] == -f[y]^2/Sqrt[2], f[y], y] /. C[1] -> y0/Sqrt[2]]
(* Sqrt[2]/(y - y0) *)
sa /. Quiet@Solve[sa == s[.731896481277023] /. y -> 10000, y0] // First
(* Sqrt[2]/(-659.96456715484941226753617557390727253613055 + y) *)
LogPlot[{Evaluate[s[.731896481277023]], If[y > 1000, %]}, {y, 0, 10000}, 
    AxesLabel -> {y, f}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

For completeness, here is a plot of the solution for small `y`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[s[.731896481277023]], {y, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {y, f}]
```

[image]

Finally, the corresponding value of the integral of `H` is

```
sint = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, f'[0] == 0, f[0] == f0}, 
    f'[y]^2 - w[y]*f[y]^2 + f[y]^4/2, {y, 0, 10000}, {f0}, WorkingPrecision -> 45];
2 NIntegrate[Evaluate[sint[.731896481277023]], {y, 0, 10000}]
(* -0.334578 *)
```

This result is insensitive to the upper bound of the integral (e.g., `1000` instead of `10000`.  This integral clearly is smaller than that of the "Discretize and Minimize" result discussed in the question and in another answer.  It also is smaller than the integral for the obvious analytical solution `f[y] = 0`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Apologies for the trivial question, but where/how are you imposing that f[y]->0 as y-> infinity? I can't seem to see that mentioned in the code

Comment: @Zonova The choice `s[.731896481277023]]` applies the boundary condition at large `y`.  Varying the value from that just given produces solutions which diverge from zero at large `y`.

Comment: @Zonova I thought that you had asked me another question, but I cannot find it.  Is there another question that you had?