# Infinite expression NDSolve conditions even with Block machine epsilon

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I have a question please.
I have an issue with my code while trying to solve an equation. Here it is :

```
sol = Block[{\[Epsilon] = $MachineEpsilon}, NDSolve[{Div[(f[x])*(1 - f[x])*Grad[(-2 f[x] + 4*f[x]^2) - Laplacian[f[x], {x, y, z}, "Spherical"], {x, y, z}, "Spherical"], {x, y, z}, "Spherical"] == \[Epsilon], f[1] == 0.6, f'[5] == \[Epsilon], f[5] == \[Epsilon],f'[\[Epsilon]]==\[Epsilon]}, f, {x, \[Epsilon], 5}]]
```

I get the following messages :

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>
```

And others of the same type. The last one is

```
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 1.`. >>
```

I don't get why since I suppressed all the zeros from my boundaries and values.

I then tried, following  (105714) :

```
xmax = 5
e = $MachineEpsilon

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{Div[(f[x])*(1 - f[x])*Grad[(-2 f[x] + 4*f[x]^3) - Laplacian[f[x], {x, y, z}, "Spherical"], {x, y, z}, "Spherical"], {x, y, z}, "Spherical"] == 0, f[1] == 0.6, f[xmax] == bc1, f'[e] == bc2, f'[xmax] == bc3}, f, {x, e, xmax}, {bc1, bc2, bc3}]

obj[bc1_?NumericQ, bc2_?NumericQ, bc3_?NumericQ] := sol[bc1, bc2, bc3][xmax]

solpc = FindRoot[obj[bc1, bc2, bc3] == 0, {{bc1, 0.1}, {bc2, 0.1}, {bc3, 0.1}}]

sols = f -> sol[bc1, bc2, bc3] /. solpc

Plot[Evaluate[f /. sols], {x, 0, 10}]
```

But  I assume I made mistakes, since I get error messages from the line with solpc :

> The function value...s not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {bc1,bc2,bc3} = \
>   {0.1,0.1,0.1}

Thx in advance !

Comment: From the posted code, I get the error, "NDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (3) (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the number of discrete variables (4)."

Comment: thx but I don't get that error in the messages ! And even when I add the constraint f'[\[Epsilon]] == \[Epsilon]  they still say me NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 2.220446049250313`*^-16. >>

Comment: The code you posted has only three boundary conditions but the DE is 4th order.  You need 4 BCs.  If you're not getting that error, I think you're not using the posted code.

Comment: In any case, I think the problem is likely to be with `"StartingInitialConditions"`.  There are several problems similar to this one on the site, which you can find if you search for "StartingInitialConditions".

Comment: Ah, in V10.4.3, I don't get the error message, but in V11.2, I do.  So the version seems important.  Which version are you using?

Comment: 10.3 so I should try with the other one ? Btw, If I modify the 4 boundary condition, sometimes there is a result, but it doesn't interess me... I tried with StartingInitialConditions too, but it didn't give much more informations. Also, I guess the issue is that the doesn't find any solution for my BC's.

Comment: I think the issue is that without carefully chosen initial conditions, the solution develops a singularity before the end (`x == 5`) is reached.  The shooting method of `NDSolve` fails in such a case. If ICs are hard to find, one might have to implement the shooting method manually. Here are some cases where I've used it: [(91854)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91854), [(105714)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105714), [(124456)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124456), [(167132)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167132)