# ODE with singularity at origin and boundary condition at $\infty$

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, singularity

I'm trying to solve the following ordinary differential equation numerically.

```
NDsolve[
  {f''[r] + 1/r f'[r] - 1/r^2 f[r] + 1/2 (1 -f[r]^2)f[r] == 0,
   f[0] == 0, f[Infinity] = 1}, 
  f[r],{r, 0, 10}]
```

I don't know how to handle this equation because of two problems:

- singularity at the origin
- boundary condition at infinity.

I would like to get an idea on how I should set up `NDSolve` under these circumstances.

Comment: This is the nonlinear Bessel's equation, which has been solved [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91854/1063).

Comment: Thanks! :) I was sure someone asked same question and tried but I could't find it.

Comment: Question [91854](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91854/1063).