# Numerical bounce solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I want to solve numerically the following differential equation

$$
y''(x) + \frac{3}{x}y'(x) = \frac{d U(y)}{y}\,,\qquad U(y) = \frac{1}{4}y(x)^2(y(x)-1)^2 -\frac{1}{400}y(x)^3
$$

in the region $x\in[0,+\infty]$ with the bounce boundary conditions

$$
y'(0) = 0\,,\qquad y(+\infty) = 0.
$$

This problem is taken from Coleman's paper (click [here](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.15.2929)) where he claims that such solution always exists, see page 4, right-column independently of the expression of the potential $U(y)$.

**I want to find such solution for the potential that I have chosen.**

This is a boundary-values problem and it is better to turn it into a initial-values problem. Let us then estimate the size of $y(0)$. It will become clear that I expect a flat direction around $x=0$, so substituting $y'(0)=0$ and $y''(0) = 0$ in the differential equation, I get an estimate for the initial condition $y(0) \sim 1$. This is just an estimate. I don't want the exact solution to satisfy $y''(0)=0$ identically, but I expect the second derivative to be small.

We can try to guess the form of the solution by making some approximations. Indeed,
I can solve analytically the differential equation for big values of $x\geq R \gg 1$, by neglecting the $1/400y(x)^3$ term in the expression of $U(y)$, as $y(0) \sim 1$ and $y(+\infty) = 0$; then, by defining $U_0(y) = \frac{1}{4}y(x)^2(y(x)-1)^2$ we can solve

$$
y''(x)= \frac{d U_0(y)}{y}\,
$$

from which we get

$$
y_R(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\text{tanh}\left[\frac{x-R}{2\sqrt{2}}\right]\right).
$$

So, roughly the approximated solution is

$$
y(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{c c}
1 & x \ll R\\
y_R(x) & x \geq R
\end{array}\right.
$$
and it is shown in the following picture for $R=400$

[image]

So, I have tried to solve numerically this Cauchy problem without any approximation by setting a cut-off $R$ on the $x$ coordinates and using the following code

```
V[y_[x_]] = 1/4 (-1 + y[x])^2 y[x]^2 - 0.0025 y[x]^3

Psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[y[x], {x, 2}] + 3/x D[y[x], x] == D[V[y[x]], y[x]], y'[10^-5] == 0, y[10^-5] == tp, WhenEvent[y[x] < 0 || y[x] > tp, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {x, 10^-5, R}, {tp, R}]

ListPlot[Table[{tp, Abs[Psol[tp, 50][50]]}, {tp, 0.8, 1.015, 0.001}]]
```

where the last line may be useful to determine the magnitude of `tp` such that I recover a vanishing asymptotic value. However, I get the following plot

[image]

So, I guess the method is not suitable for this problem. In particular, the solution `Mathematica` finds does not respect the asymptotic boundary condition $y(+\infty) = 0$ at $x=50$, and moreover it starts oscillating after some time like in the following picture and does not go to zero at infinity

[image]

How can I get the numerical solution?

Comment: My recommendation for you is to solve for your bounce using the shooting method described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97733/2048).

Comment: @QuantumDot thanks. I have tried to use shooting methods but without any success. BTW I am not an expert of numerical methods.

Comment: The initial value problem solver of `NDSolve` is very robust, the result given by your code only suggests one thing in my view: there just exists no solution satisfying $y(0)∼1,y′(0)=0,y(+∞)=0$.

Comment: @xzczd thank you for the comment. I have also thought about the non-existence of the solution. However, the fact that the approximate solution does exist and the term $\sim 1/400 y(x)^3$ is very small, makes me hoping that the exact numerical solution does exist as well. Is my impression too naive?

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert of symbolic ODE analysing, but I just _feel_ the $y′(x)/x$ term cannot be ignored, because when $x$ isn't that large, the contribution of this term is not small. (For $x=R$, $y_R(R)=1/2$. )

Comment: @xzczd you are right for generic initial conditions, but in my case $y'(0) = 0$ helps you to avoid such contribution, because the direction is flat

Comment: But you've imposed $y(+∞)=0$, so the solution isn't that flat in $[R, +∞)$.

Comment: Yes, but it you take R sufficiently large, as in the example, this term never becomes huge. For example, regarding the approximate solution I have found for $R=400$, the term $y'(x)/x$ has maximum value $ 10^{-2}$ at around $x=400$, which is negligible (or at most comparable) wrt to the value of the RHS evaluated at $x=400$. So, I expect the full solution to have this shape, up to minor modifications, such as the slope of the curve for large values of $x$ and the initial condition $y'(0)$.

Comment: If you impose the two conditions $y'(0)=y''(0)=0$, it's not clear to me you can expect $y(+\infty)=0$ to be satisfied.

Comment: @MichaelE2 actually I am not requiring the exact solution to satisfy $y''(0)=0$; I used it to estimate the size of $y(0)$. For instance, what about if $y''(0) = 10^{-1}$ and still $y'(0)=0$? Yet $y(0)\sim 1$ and maybe you can get the asymptotic value $y(+\infty)=0$, right?

Comment: @MichaelE2 This problem is taken from Coleman's paper https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.15.2929 where he claims that such solutions always exists, see page 4, right-column

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The argument in the paper linked in the comments suggests that if one starts close enough to the one equilbrium at $y \approx c_1 = 1.04$, then the asymptotically vanishing solution may be found.  Below is a solution that is not quite there.  It starts at $x = 10^{-8}$ at $y = c_1 - 10^{-25}$ and uses `WorkingPrecision -> 50`; it certainly needs more than machine precision to ensure that $y$ does not round to $c_1$.  It's not close enough.  Getting close enough seems to require a very small difference and consequently a very high working precisions.  But `NDSolve` fails when I push it, indicating an error test failure (`NDSolveValue::nderr`).  It may be that for such an example to be computationally feasible, you need a greater difference in the value of `V[x]` at the minima.

```
ClearAll[V];
V[y_] = 1/4 (-1 + y)^2 y^2 - 25/10000 y^3;
ode = y''[x] + (3 y'[x])/x == V'[y[x]];

wp = 50;
cps = NSolve[V'[y] == 0, WorkingPrecision -> wp];

ndsol[x0_?NumericQ, x1_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, yp_?NumericQ] := 
  NDSolveValue[{ode, y'[x1] == yp, y[x1] == y0, 
    WhenEvent[y[x] < 0, "StopIntegration"],
    WhenEvent[y[x] > 49/100 && x > x1, "StopIntegration"]}, 
   y, {x, x0, 10000}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> Precision@{x0, x1, y0, yp}];
ListLinePlot[
 ndsol[2^-50, 1/10^8, y - 10^-25 /. Last@cps, 0],
 PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 2}}]
```

[image]

---

**Update**

Here is a better result, FWIW.  The method `"Extrapolation"` is more robust on this problem.

```
wp = 150;  (* working precision *)
cps = NSolve[V'[y] == 0, WorkingPrecision -> wp]; 
iObj[x0_?NumericQ, x1_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, yp_?NumericQ] := 
 Catch@NDSolveValue[{ode, y'[x1] == yp, y[x1] == y0, 
    WhenEvent[y[x] < 0, Throw[x]],
    WhenEvent[y[x] > 49/100 && x > x1, Throw[$Failed]],
    WhenEvent[y[x] > 2 && x > x1, Throw[$Failed]]}, y, {x, x0, 1000}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> Precision@{x0, x1, y0, yp}, 
   Method -> "Extrapolation"];
obj[dy_?NumericQ] := iObj[2^-50, 1/10^8, y - 10^dy /. Last@cps, 0];

foo = Nest[  (* bisection method for finding optimal IC *)
  With[{mid = obj[Mean@#]},
    Switch[mid,
     $Failed, {First@#, Mean@#},
     _?NumericQ, {Mean@#, Last@#},
     _, {First@#, Mean@#}
     ]
    ] &,
  {-42 - 54/100, -42 - 53/100},
  60
  ]
(*
  {-(2452178951689226635963/57646075230342348800), 
   -(196174316135138130877/4611686018427387904)}
 *)
ndsol[x0_?NumericQ, x1_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, yp_?NumericQ] := 
  NDSolveValue[{ode, y'[x1] == yp, y[x1] == y0, 
    WhenEvent[y[x] < 0, "StopIntegration"],
    WhenEvent[y[x] > 49/100 && x > x1, "StopIntegration"],
    WhenEvent[y[x] > 2 && x > x1, "StopIntegration"]}, 
   y, {x, x0, 10000}, WorkingPrecision -> Precision@{x0, x1, y0, yp}, 
   Method -> "Extrapolation"];
ListLinePlot[
 ndsol[2^-50, 1/10^8, y - 10^dy /. Last@cps, 0] /. dy -> First@foo,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Ehi Michael E2, thank you! I am trying to reproduce your result. Which version of Mathematica are you using? I am not able to reproduce your plots, by just copy and past your code, see here the screenshot https://ibb.co/4jdM6Fv

Comment: @apt45 I think the problem is that a couple of days ago I changed the def. of `V[]` so that the derivative would work with prime.  I forgot about that.  I included the new def. of `V[]` just now.  If that doesn't work, I'm using V11.3 on a Mac.  I doubt that would be a problem.

Comment: Thanks! Now I am able to produce the first plot, whereas regarding the second I get Error test failure like in the screenshot https://ibb.co/9hzgnJR . It may be a problem with the Working precision?

Comment: @apt45 Sorry again.  I posted just before going to bed.  I changed `ndsol[]` to use `"Extrapolation"`; code included.  The default method (LSODA) gives those conv. test errors.

Comment: Great! Fantastic! Now It works! I am going to study the code. Thank you!

Comment: Last question.. is there a logic in choosing the value of WorkingPrecision? If I modify the last piece of potential, for example by enlarging the difference between the two minima $\sim 1/1000 y^3$, even the Extrapolation method fails and returns a solution similar to your first plot. So, it may be that I have to modify WorkingPrecision. But how? increse? decrese?

Comment: @apt45 Two issues with the working precision are that (1) the initial condition $y_0=c_1-10^{-p}$ should be a distinct number from the critical value $c_1$ and (2) the difference $y_0-c_1$ should have sufficient precision. For (1) the WP should be more than $p$ and for (2) the rule of thumb is twice that or $2p$. Since I didn't know $p$ at the beginning, I put a `1` in front of the `50` from the first answer to get `wp = 150`, which turned out to be good enough. Beyond that, because the asymptotic solution is unstable, an unknown amount extra precision is needed to keep the solution on track.

Answer (score 7):

*(Not an answer, an extended comment.)*

> So, I guess the method is not suitable for this problem. How can I get the numerical solution??"

Those statement and question do not make much sense to me. You already have the numerical solution. Why do you think the method is not suitable? The message InterpolationFunction::dmval is avoided if you decrease the range of `tp` a little (with 0.001). Study this result plot:

```
ListPlot[Table[{tp, Abs[Psol[tp, 50][50]]}, {tp, 0.8, 1.014, 0.001}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Also, maybe you should study the solution behavior for different values of the independent variable `x` not just 50.

For example, the following 3D plot gives an idea of the found solution behavior with respect to both `tp` and `x`. (We can see the "bouncing" along the x-axis.)

```
points = Flatten[Table[{tp, x, Abs[Psol[tp, 50][x]]}, {tp, 0.8, 1.014, 0.001}, {x, 1, 50, 1}], 1];
ListPlot3D[points, AxesLabel -> {"tp", "x", "y"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I am requiring my function to decay at infinity (see the second boundary condition). The solution you claim to have found does not seem to decay to zero for large `x`, even if I choose `R=600`

Comment: @apt45 "The solution you claim to have found" -- read carefully what I wrote. I am  not claiming to have found any solution, I am using your solution found with the code you posted.

Comment: Indeed! It is not the solution with the boundary conditions I have imposed! This is why I said that my method was not suitable

Comment: BTW I know you have copied and past my code, and then the function is the same that I got. For this reason, the question is still open, as I am not able to find the solution to the Cauchy problem in the OP

Comment: Anton have you seen the updated question?

Comment: @apt45 Yes. When I saw your update it seemed you were getting the help you requested from others...

Answer (score 4):

OK, [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)'s answer gives me the courage to post the following as an answer. It seems that finite difference method (FDM) can be used to find the solutions for this problem in a relatively easy way. I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of finite difference equations:

```
Clear[V];
V[y_] = 1/4 (-1 + y)^2 y^2 - 25/10000 y^3;
ode = y''[x] + (3 y'[x])/x == V'[y[x]];    
newode = # x & /@ ode // Simplify
inf = 50;
domain = {0, inf};
bc = {y'[0] == 0, y[inf] == 0};
points = 500;
difforder = 2;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[y[x], grid, difforder];
ae = ptoafunc[newode][[2 ;; -2]];
aebc = ptoafunc@bc;

initial[x_] := 2;
sollst = FindRoot[{ae, aebc}, Table[{y@x, initial@x}, {x, grid}]][[All, -1]];
ListLinePlot[sollst, DataRange -> domain]
sol = ListInterpolation[sollst, grid];
(* Error check: *)
Plot[Subtract @@ ode /. y -> sol // Evaluate, {x, 0, inf}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I hesitated to post this because:

1. Using different `inf`, I can find different solutions, e.g. `inf = 100`:
   [image: Mathematica graphics]
2. The error of the solution isn't that small, and even if I increase `points`, I cannot observe obvious error reduction:

   [image: Mathematica graphics]

But now, reading all the analysis above, I believe there just exist multiple solutions for the problem, and the code above is worth sharing.

Comment: I think this is reasonable because theoretically we know there's a solution, so you know you're approximating something that really exists.  OTOH, the sensitivity to the truncation error near `x == inf` (I assume) seems to affect the computed solution quite a lot.