# BVP of coupled ODEs with unknown initial values

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear

I want to solve the following 2nd order coupled ODEs:

$$
\begin{align}
f^{\prime \prime} (r) + \frac{2}{r} f^{\prime} (r) + f (r) g (r)^2 - f     (r) + f (r)^3 - \frac{1}{5} f (r)^5 &= 0 \\
    g^{\prime \prime} (r) + \frac{2}{r} g^{\prime} (r) - f (r)^2 g (r) &= 0
\end{align}
$$

with the boundary conditions

$$
    \begin{equation}
    f^{\prime} (0) = 0 = g^{\prime} (0)     \\  
    f (\infty) = 0     \\
    g (\infty) = \omega
    \end{equation}
$$

where $\omega$ is a parameter in the range $\frac{3}{16} < \omega < 1$.

In [91854](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/nonlinear-differential-equation-numerical-solution/97733#97733), there is a powerful method for solving ODE by shooting.
For the coupled ODE system, however, it cannot shoot.

Here is my code:

````
```mathematica
(* Original equation *)
fxeq = f''[x] + 2 (f'[x]/x) + f[x] g[x]^2 - f[x] + f[x]^3 - 1/5 f[x]^5;
gxeq = g''[x] + 2 (g'[x]/x) - f[x]^2 g[x];

(* Choosing the value of \[Omega] *)
\[Omega] = 1/2;

(* Change of variable *)
xsub = First@
    Solve[{v[t] == f[x[t]], p == D[f[x[t]], t], q == D[f[x[t]], t, t],
       u[t] == g[x[t]], r == D[g[x[t]], t], 
      s == D[g[x[t]], t, t]}, {f[x[t]], f'[x[t]], f''[x[t]], g[x[t]], 
      g'[x[t]], g''[x[t]]}] /. {p -> v'[t], q -> v''[t], r -> u'[t], 
    s -> u''[t]};

xf = #/(1 - #) &;
tf = #/(1 + #) &;
With[{v2 = 
First@Solve[{fxeq, gxeq} /. x -> x[t] /. xsub /. x -> xf // 
    Factor // # == 0 &, {v''[t], u''[t]}]}, {vtRHS = v''[t] /. v2,
    utRHS = u''[t] /. v2}];
vteq = v''[t] == vtRHS
uteq = u''[t] == utRHS


Clear[rhs];
Block[{v0, u0, 
  t, \[Epsilon] = $MachineEpsilon}, {vrhsFN[v0_, u0_][t_] = 
    Piecewise[{{vtRHS, t != \[Epsilon] && t != 1}, {v0, 
   t == \[Epsilon]}}, 0], 
   urhsFN[v0_, u0_][t_] = 
   Piecewise[{{utRHS, t != \[Epsilon] && t != 1}, {u0, 
     t == \[Epsilon]}}, 0]};]
(* Making a guess of the initial value *)
psolmp = Block[{\[Epsilon] = $MachineEpsilon}, 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{v''[t] == vrhsFN[v0, u0][t], 
v[\[Epsilon]] == v0, v'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, 
u''[t] == urhsFN[v0, u0][t], u[\[Epsilon]] == u0, 
u'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, WhenEvent[v[t] < 0, "StopIntegration"], 
WhenEvent[u'[t] > 0, "StopIntegration"], 
WhenEvent[u[t] < 0, "StopIntegration"]}, {v, u}, {t, \[Epsilon], 
1}, {v0, u0}]]

Clear[objmp];
objmp[v0_?NumericQ, u0_?NumericQ] := 
psolmp[v0, u0][[1]]["Domain"][[1, -1]]
{tmaxmp, {parammpv, parammpu}} = 
 FindMaximum[{objmp[v0, u0], v0 > 0, 0 < u0 < \[Omega]}, {v0, 
   11/10}, {u0, 1/10}, AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 20]
vsolmp = v -> psolmp[v0 /. parammpv, u0 /. parammpu][[1]];
usolmp = u -> psolmp[v0 /. parammpv, u0 /. parammpu][[2]];
xf[tmaxmp]


Plot[{v[tf[x]] /. vsolmp, u[tf[x]] /. usolmp}, {x, 0., xf[tmaxmp]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```
````

The initial value I want is $ 0 < u0 < \omega $, however, u0 becomes negative in my result such as

[image: shooting result]

How can I solve this problem?